# Please help identify sci fi novel for kids about a new earth colony ship that's disintegrating

Tags: story-identification, generation-ship

I can remember these details:

- The ship is disintegrating because years ago it passed through a cloud containing organisms that are now eating through its hull
- Nobody is able to figure out how to get rid of the organisms
- It's a generation ship. The main characters were born there and are the latest of many generations who have never lived on a planet
- The ship is not going to make it to the new earth colony before it disintegrates
- The main characters encounter some other beings (can't remember details) that help them travel faster than light to arrive at their destination

I got this book at a school book fair when I was in maybe 6th or 7th grade (early 80s). I can't remember the author or the title, but would love to rediscover it and/or share it with my kids.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Take a look at the [help page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) for story identification questions, see if anything will jog your memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it The Watchers Of Space? Here is a link to amazon for it, maybe the cover art looks familiar?
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/038075374X/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038075374X)

> Synopsis: The starship Genesis carries the last survivors of Earth on a desperate flight to a new home. But the ship is slowly disintegrating and the oxygen supply is running out -- it's a race against time and space. Out of the far reaches of the universe the Watchers of Space gather: Orion, the giant golden man; Starnight, the sword of power and magic; and Cygnus, the beautiful swan. Together they will help save the doomed ship. But no one on the Genesis will believe twelve-year-old William when he tells them of the Watchers' plan. For they no longer believe in anything -- not till they see William go spinning off into space...

Comment: Yes! I believe that's it! Wow; thank you!